# Android Studio: Button alignment in table row

Tags: java, android-studio, button

Im developing and app in android Studio and now I've faced a strange problem.

I have a `tableRow`that contents a `TextView` and a `Button`.

I'm building them programmatically and I want the `button`inside the `tableRow`to align to the right side of the screen.

I've already tried so many options like:

`button.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT)` and `button.setGravity(Gravity.END)` and tried to give layout params to the table with with `fill_parent` in the `layout_width`but doesn't seem's to work.

Here's the part of the code where I build the `TableRow`:

```
  TableRow new_tablerow = new TableRow(getContext());
                        layout_pickup_passengers.addView(new_tablerow);

                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams rowParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        new_tablerow.setLayoutParams(rowParams);

                        //GLOBAL PASSENGERS
                        TextView text_pass_type = new TextView(getContext());
                        new_tablerow.addView(text_pass_type);
                        text_pass_type.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                        text_pass_type.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 22);
                        text_pass_type.setText("> Passageiros");

                        //BUTTON
                        // Button
                        final Button button_numberPickerDialog = new Button(getContext());
                        button_numberPickerDialog.setBackgroundResource(R.color.wallet_bright_foreground_holo_dark);
                        new_tablerow.addView(button_numberPickerDialog);
                        button_numberPickerDialog.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

So has you can see only the Text inside aligns to the right (the 0 number), and I want the button to allign to the right not the text inside it.

Answer (score 0):

The method "`setGravity(int)`" you mention here couldn't work as you imagined because the method's work is same as the attribute "`andriod:gravity`" in xml which can not affect button you defined obviously.

Actually, I wonder why you insist building them programmatically. I guess if you build them in xml, use "`android : layout_gravity`" can work.

---

I try to use `RaletiveLayout` to make that work here's the code:

```
//TableRow new_tablerow = new TableRow(getBaseContext());
        //layout_pickup_passengers.addView(new_tablerow);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        layout_pickup_passengers.addView(relativeLayout,params);

        //GLOBAL PASSENGERS
        TextView text_pass_type = new TextView(getBaseContext());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp_text = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        lp_text.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        text_pass_type.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        text_pass_type.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 22);
        text_pass_type.setText("> Passageiros");
        relativeLayout.addView(text_pass_type,lp_text);

        //BUTTON
        // Button
        final Button button_numberPickerDialog = new Button(getBaseContext());
        button_numberPickerDialog.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp_button = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        lp_button.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        relativeLayout.addView(button_numberPickerDialog,lp_button);
```

perhaps I make a bit change to your code.
could it sacrifice you?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxEcA.png)

Comment: I cant build them in xml because its a booking app, and this part depends of the previous user choices in the application

Comment: well, as for me, maybe I'll try to use RelativeLayout as a View instead

Comment: I need a `TableLayout` because in some cases I need to add more `tableRows` to it and it need to be aligned

Comment: sorry,I was failed to find another effective solution.G'Luck!